# What are the dangers in re-using variables in a data source?

Tags: adobe-analytics

Not quite sure if this is on topic, so when in doubt feel free to close.

We have a client who is missing tracking data for a large segment of his visitors in his Report Suite. However the complete set of data is available in a data warehouse. We are now investigating if it is possible to import them as a data source. I have only experience with enriching data via classifications, however the goal here is to create views (sessions etc) for a past timeframe etc from scratch.

According to the documentation this should be possible. However there is one caveat specifically mentioned in the FAQ:

> "Adobe recommends you select new, unused variables to import data
>   using Data Sources. If you are uncertain about the configuration of
>   your data file, or want to better understand the risks of re-using
>   variables, contact Customer Care.“

I take that to mean that I should not import data to props,Evars,events etc. that have been used when data has been collected via the tracker, which would pretty much defeat our purpose (basically we want to merge the data from the data warehouse with existing data). Since I have to go to some intermediaries to reach customer care and this takes a long time I wonder if somebody here can explain what the dangers in re-using variables are (and maybe even if there is still a way to do this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have since received an answer from Adobe Customer Care.

According to them the issue is that hits created via data imports are indistinguishable from hits created via server calls, so they cannot be removed or corrected after they have been imported. They recommend to use different variables so that the original data remains recognizable and salvageable in case one does import faulty data via the imports.

This was already mentioned in the online documentation, but apparently Adobe thinks this is important enough to issue the extra warning.

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER:** I'm not familiar with Adobe Analytics, but the problem here is pretty universal. If someone with actual experience/knowledge specific to the product comes along, pay more attention to them than me :)

As a rule, Variable reuse in any system runs the risk of data corruption. I'm not familiar with Adobe Analytics, but a brief read through some [blogs](http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmarketing/analytics/data-organization-variable-usage-within-the-report-suite/) imply that this is what they're worried about in terms of variable reuse - if you have a variable that is being used in one section, and you import data into it in another section when is in the same scope, you overwrite the data that the other section was using.

Now, that same blog states that provided you have your data structure set up in a specific way, it can allow you to reuse variables/properties without issue and in fact encourages it, hence the statement in your quote "If you are uncertain about the configuration of your data file...". They're probably warning you that if you know what you're doing and know that there won't be any overwriting, fine, go ahead and reuse, but if you don't, or you aren't sure whether something else might be using the original content, then it's unsafe.

Regarding your specific case, you want to merge the two piece of data together, not overwrite, so reusing your existing variables would overwrite the existing data. Sounds like you will need to import to a second (new) set of variables, and then compare/merge between them within the system, rather than trying to import and merge in one go.